# Buffering follow + automatic pagination of output

Tags: shell, terminal, pipe, less, more

I have a utility that continuously outputs live logs from a program. But it can be quite hard to read the logs lines as they scroll past me in the terminal. Ideally it should scroll to one full page, and then pause until there is a full new screen of logs ready to be shown and then automatically scroll to that.

Is it possible to pipe the output to some utility such as `less` or `more` to get pagination, but at the same time have it buffer the following output until a new page is ready and then automatically scroll without user input to the next page?

Answer (score 1):

In early 2022, I developed a utility called [`pw`](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about) (PipeWatch) for watching fast/voluminous outputs.

In `pw` you can set regex-driven triggers for dynamically capturing snapshots of the text that is passing through it. There is a history of 20 snapshots you can flip through.

You can put `pw` into the background; it continues to run, consume input from the pipe and capture snapshots.

The above plug aside, `less` does pagination. When you use the <kbd>F</kbd> command, then you are in follow mode which is a bit like `tail -f`. You can interrupt that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get back to `less`'s command mode, in which you can use the arrow keys, <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> or commands similar to Vi commands to move around in the file, not to mention <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>?</kbd> for searching. `less` just doesn't do pagination in follow mode.